# JPA Cache configuration

Tags: java, caching, jpa

There actually is an interface, javax.persistence.Cache but I can't find a way to specify the cache provider in the persistence.xml! Do I have to use the vendor specific way to declare a cache or are is there anything I don't know?

I would like to propose a config value for persistence.xml in the JPA Spec if there is currently no possibillity to declare it.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53562/enabling-hibernate-second-level-cache-with-jpa-on-jboss-4-2

Comment: Vendor way is the only way. Also this is not the place to propose something in a spec ... better to try http://java.net/projects/jpa-spec/lists  and mail their list. Obviously all JPA implementations don't support all available open-source/commercial cache implementations so unlikely to be accepted in that form

Comment: And http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjio.html

Comment: I did not want to propose it here, I just wanted to make sure that this possibillity does not exist, but thanks for the answer!

Comment: BTW if anyone gets along here and wants information about the current status, see http://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-32